RabbitMQ vhost exists in `list_vhosts`, but can't be found by `delete_vhost` command. How do I delete it?
When I list the vhosts, the vhost xms clearly shows up.
$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_vhosts
Listing vhosts ...
name
/
xms
xms_test

But when I try to delete it, it seems to not exist
$ sudo rabbitmqctl delete_vhost "xms"
Deleting vhost "xms" ...
Virtual host 'xms' does not exist
$ sudo rabbitmqctl delete_vhost "/xms"
Deleting vhost "/xms" ...
Virtual host '/xms' does not exist

Just to confirm it was not deleted in the meantime, I checked list_vhosts again and got the same result. I also tried sudo service rabbitmq-server restart but it did not fix anything.
I need this phantom zombie vhost to go away.
Am I just getting some command syntax wrong?
Does it actually exist or not?
How can I delete it properly?

For clarity, I'll mention that xms_test is in the same weird state. And there are also a dozen other vhosts, but I omitted them because they seem to be perfectly normal and I don't need to delete them.

I was able to clear my immediate problem by resetting the whole server and nuking everything. But I am still very curious what was up.
